# Do pool servers communicate with bitcoind, and in what capacity?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, getwork, stratum, getblocktemplate

I'm trying to understand how the whole process flows. Here's how I currently understand it working.

> Mining client -> Pool server -> Bitcoind
>
> `getwork`:
>
> - Mining client calls `getwork` from Pool server, and it in turn calls `getwork` (or something else?) from Bitcoind.
>
> `stratum`:
>
> - Mining client ingages the Pool server using the stratum protocol, and the Pool server calls `getwork` (or something else?) from
>     Bitcoind.
>
> `getblocktemplate`:
>
> - Mining client calls `getblocktemplate`, and the Pool server calls `getblocktemplate` from Bitcoind.

And I understand that the pool server does more than just relay information, but I wanted to keep it simple. I just want to get a grasp of how it all flows together, and what calls it makes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getwork` is for all intents, completely deprecated due to it's inefficiency. At this point a single ASIC device can completely swamp a `bitcoind` with requests as they're able to exhaust the 32bit nonce in a fraction of a second. The situation is severe enough that pools like BTC Guild have extraordinary large (6%+) fees on clients using `getwork` in order to get them to switch to more efficient methods.

Internally, pools like [Eloipool](https://gitorious.org/bitcoin/eloipool/) use `getblocktemplate` to generate work for the clients, and then use `stratum` or `getblocktemplate` to communicate with the workers depending on the request type they make. `getwork` is not involved at any stage. In fact, it's currently [pegged for complete removal](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2905) at some point.

Comment: So, `Eloipool` is pretty much relaying the same getblocktemplate they receive from bitcoind?

Comment: From looking at `jsonrpc_getblocktemplate.py`, I would say so.

Comment: Thanks again. I would up-vote you, but I don't have enough points.